# JFrame won't load the images I want it to

Tags: image, swing, jframe, bufferedimage, jcomponent

Please be patient with me.. I'm very new to Java.

I have two separate JFrames and the first loads the background I want but when I dispose the first JFrame and load the second one it loads with the background from the first.

**j1.java**

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

    public class j1 extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
        public bg1 img;
        public bg2 img2;

        public j1() { 
            lvl1();
        }

        private JFrame lvl1() { 
            this.img=new bg1();
            addKeyListener(this);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
            setTitle("lvl1");
            setResizable(false);
            setSize(600, 600);
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().add(img);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
            return(this);
        }

        private JFrame lvl2() {
            this.img2=new bg2();
            addKeyListener(this);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
            setTitle("lvl2");
            setResizable(false);
            setSize(600, 600);
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().add(img2);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
            return(this);
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 
            if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                lvl1().dispose();
                lvl2();
                }
        }
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new j1();
        }
    }
```

**bg1.java**

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class bg1 extends JComponent {
        public BufferedImage person;
        public BufferedImage background;
        public bg1() { 
            loadImages2();
    }

        public void loadImages2() {
            try {
                String personn = "Images/person.gif";
                person = ImageIO.read(new File(personn));
                String backgroundd = "Images/background2.jpg";
                background = ImageIO.read(new File(backgroundd));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
            g.drawImage(person, 100, 100, this);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new bg1();
        }
    }
```

bg2.java is very similar to bg1.java but it has different names for the images and voids.

Comment: *"bg2.java is very similar to bg1.java but it has different names for the images and voids."* - Really?  Well, since this seems to be giving you some issues, you might consider providing it as well

Comment: While we're scratching our heads over this, you might consider having a look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for an alternative solution and [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you kind of have a series of problems.

First, this is one of the dangers of re-using a frame this way, basically, you never actually remove `bg1` from the frame, you just keep adding new instances of the `bg2`.  This means that `bg1` is still visible and valid on the frame...

Second, you're calling `lvl1()` AGAIN before you call `lvl2`, which is making a new instance of `bg1` and adding that to the window and then disposing of it (which does NOT dispose of the components) and then you add a new instance of `lvl2` to the frame and the whole thing is just one big mess.

Instead, you should simply be using a `CardLayout` which will allow you to switch between the individual views more elegantly.  See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for moer details.

You should also have a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of using `KeyListener`

As general rule of thumb, you should avoid overriding `JFrame`, this has a nasty habit of just confusing the whole thing.  Simple create a new instance of a `JFrame` when you need it and add you components directly to it.  Before anyone takes that the wrong way, you'll also want to have a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)